# Expressing a dictionary that returns string and list of values in my py

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

I am new to python and very new to using types. I have some function that returns a dictionary where the `key` is a string and `value` is a list of strings. I want to know what is the correct way to express this using types.

**Sample output**

```
{"lebron": ["king","goat","bron"], "jordan": ["clutch", "goat", "bulls"]}
```

**Code**

```
from typing import Any, Dict, List

def foo_bar() -> Dict[str, Any]:
    my_map: Dict[str, Any] = {}
    # some stuff happens
    return my_map


def foo_bar() -> Dict[str, List[str]]:
    my_map: Dict[str, List[str]] = {}
    # some stuff happens
    return my_map
```

I have posted two approaches one is more specific which is `Dict[str, List[str]]` but i have never seen anyone use this anywhere so i am not sure if it is correct.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this question should be edited for clarity or deleted altogether but, please, see: [Why is "Is this correct?" an off-topic question, and what should I ask instead?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359466)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both type annotations are correct. You should prefer to use `Dict[str, List[str]]` for being more specific.

**Addendum**: specificity is preferable in this situation, in other cases generality might be more preferable.

Comment: makes sense for instance if i was returning a dictionary where i have str as key and list of str has value in some cases and str has value in other cases then i would use `Any` right

Comment: You might, or you might use `Dict[str, Union[List[str], str]]`, or, say `Dict[str, Sequence[str]]`, depending on your needs.

Comment: what does union indicate?

Comment: `Union[A, B]` represents values with a type of either `A` or `B`. Check out the documentation for [`typing.Union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union).

Answer (score 2):

No need to follow the ancient way of defining variables in python. Python itself take care of data types.
Just do

```
a = dict()
```

or

```
a = {}
```

and then

```
a["mylist1"] = ["item1", "item2"]
b["mylist2"] = ["item1", "item2"]
```

But what methods you have posted are also correct.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly define the function which takes string and value.
In second line initiate dictionary.
In third step you can directly start assigning values to the key.

```
def foo_bar(string, val):
    my_map = dict()
    my_map[string] = val 
    return my_map
```

In this case string is the key and val is the value

So in your case

```
my_map = dict()
my_map["lebron"] = ["king","goat","bron"]
my_map["jordan"]: ["clutch", "goat", "bulls"]
print(my_map)
```

It must give desired output.

Comment: Have a look at the edit.

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question